# How to make apt in Debian not care about a version mismatch?

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I used `dpkg` to force install some packages (openjdk) from a different Debian release (Sid) on to my current install (Stretch). It seems to work (can compile a "hello world") *but* trying to install anything afterwards complains about a `libc6` version mismatch.

How can I get the issue ignored?

*Alternatively* is there another way to get a variety of openjdk versions available to the same base install? I am not willing to use Sid as my base.

Answer (score 4):

You can’t ignore the issue...

There are however a couple of ways to fix it.

1. You can upgrade to Debian 10: this currently has a version of OpenJDK close to that in unstable, and will soon have exactly the same.
2. You can install OpenJDK (11) from Stretch backports; this is identical to the version in unstable, but built against Stretch’s packages.

The latter is probably the simpler:

```
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t stretch-backports openjdk-11-jdk
```

You might still have to deal with *some* fallout from your libc discrepancies, but the details there depend on exactly what you upgraded along with OpenJDK.

You can have OpenJDK 8 and 11 installed in parallel in this fashion, and use whichever is appropriate by setting `JAVA_HOME` accordingly. The system-wide default version of Java can be set by running `update-java-alternatives`.

To install older versions of Java, you can try installing package sets from Debian snapshots; you’ll find [OpenJDK 6](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/openjdk-6/) and [OpenJDK 7](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/openjdk-7/). I wouldn’t try versions 9 and 10, because they were never released in a stable distribution; they shouldn’t be needed anyway.

Whatever you do, don’t try installing packages from newer releases of Debian, and don’t use `dpkg`’s `--force` options.

Comment: I need as far back as openjdk-6 . I am creating a vagrant box to serve as a base for have working environments for our offshore developers to have consistent environments while they work on maintenance projects. Some of our old projects require Java 6. Because of JigSaw I cannot just run the latest JDK and configure the source version.

Comment: Is your question about fixing your dependency problem, or about installing multiple versions of OpenJDK, going back to OpenJDK 6?

Comment: Well it's sort of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I need the same base install with lots of different JDKs (from 6 onwards). I am trying to solve it using DPKG force, but it results in the question at hand.

Comment: that's because dpkg's `--force*` options are not for everyday use.  they are "break glass in case of emergency" tools to help with fixing serious problems, by temporarily breaking some part(s) of the system to make it easier to fix the whole system.

Comment: @ArtB OK, I’ve added links for OpenJDK 6 and 7.